# is there any powerful tool for migrations in elastic-search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, indexing, migration

I am trying to synchronise my mongodb with elasticsearch. My primary requirement for it is to automatically reflect all changes in mongodb to elasticsearch. So all the collections in the mongodb will be the index of elasticsearch. it will also be needed to customise the tool configuration that it only sync the specific collections with the elasticsearch. Please refer any suitable tool for it.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by migration?

Comment: @EladAmit question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect tool [monstache](https://github.com/rwynn/monstache) for realtime syncing of mongodb with elastic-search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/ to stream the mongodb changes to kafka and then use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html to push them to elasticsearch